# HTML Slide Menu for a Mobile HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I want to make a slide menu for a mobile html page.

**Is there a jquery library still able to do that? How can I do this myself?**

There should be a menu button on the top left of the screen. 
[image]

If I tap the menu button the content should slide to the right and the menu bar would appears on the left.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this page to get details

http://www.berriart.com/sidr/

https://github.com/donwalter/jquery-mobile-slide-menu

Include the following files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-mobile-slide-menu.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-mobile-slide-menu.js"></script>
```

Then insert your menu, before your  tag:

```
<div id="side-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Main</a><span class="icon"></span></li>
        <li><a href="/page-2/">Page 2</a><span class="icon"></span></li>
        <li><a href="/page-3/">Page 3</a><span class="icon"></span></li>
        <li><a href="/page-4/">Page 4</a><span class="icon"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then add this to initiate the menu:

```
$(function(){
    $('#side-menu').slideMenu();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/jquery/1.9.1/5624435/)